# Qual è il significato di "cavar gli occhi" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Ignaro di come fosse fatto il bosco, ma sicuro d’eseguire a puntino gli ordini ricevuti, l’ufficialetto procedeva secondo le linee tracciate sulla carta, prendendo continuamente delle nasate contro i tronchi, facendo scivolare la truppa con le scarpe chiodate su pietre lisce o **cavar gli occhi** nei roveti, ma sempre conscio della supremazia delle armi imperiali.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "cavar gli occhi" in questo brano. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cavare/) ho trovato

> *ti caverei il cuore, gli occhi*, frasi di minaccia, o piuttosto di sfogo (cui quasi mai corrisponde, neanche al livello del subconscio, una reale intenzione di far seguire i fatti alle parole). Locuzioni fig.: *cavarsi gli occhi*, affaticare la vista nel decifrare una scrittura minuta

Tuttavia, queste definizioni non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 1):

Il significato è che l’ufficialetto faceva correre un sacco di rischi alle sue truppe, facendogli dare nasate nei tronchi, passare su rocce scivolose senza l’equipaggiamento adeguato e a rischio di perdere gli occhi con le spine.

Nelle frasi di minaccia che hai trovato l’espressione cavare gli occhi significa strappare fisicamente gli occhi dalle orbite, cosa che possono fare le spine di rovi particolarmente intricati.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe quello letterale di "lasciare una cavità" nel viso "levando" gli occhi dei soldati?

Comment: Il discorso è che l’ufficiale era sconsiderato e esponeva le sue truppe ad un sacco di rischi. Tra questi il passare in mezzo a roveti irti di spine che potevano ferire seriamente gli occhi dei soldati e, nei casi estremi, estirpare anche un occhio. Diciamo che quest’ultimo evento è forse esagerato ma secondo me l’intenzione dell’autore è porre l’accento sulla inettitudine dell’ufficiale.